# how to check code duplication in magento 2 Extension?

Tags: magento2, marketplace

I have created a module in Magento 2 and now I am trying to submit it on Magento Marketplace.
My extension has passed from business review and Technical review but I am facing issues with QA review.

I recieved a mail from Magento marketplace stating that I had code duplication in my extension.
Below is the sample of the mail.

> Code quality issues: CPD: This extension contains duplicated code.

When I went to my product on Marketplace account, and checked the technical report, I found below.

Code Duplicates Detected

This extension contains code that is directly copied from the Magento codebase. This is in direct violation of Sections 3.1 and 9.1b of the Magento Developer Agreement.

```
File: vendor/module/vendor-module-1.0.0.0/Block/Adminhtml/Module/Edit/Tab/Stores.php
Line: 58
File: magento/module-checkout-agreements/magento-module-checkout-agreements-100.0.6.0/Block/Adminhtml/Agreement/Edit/Form.php
Line: 122

File: magento/module-cms/magento-module-cms-100.0.7.0/Block/Adminhtml/Block/Edit/Form.php
Line: 100
File: vendor/module/vendor-module-1.0.0.0/Block/Adminhtml/Module/Renderer/Files.php
Line: 49

File: magento/framework/magento-framework-100.0.16.0/Data/Form/Element/Image.php
Line: 86
File: vendor/module/vendor-module-1.0.0.0/Model/ResourceModel/AbstractCollection.php
Line: 2
File: magento/module-cms/magento-module-cms-100.0.7.0/Model/ResourceModel/AbstractCollection.php
Line: 6
```

Is there any way I can check for code duplication on my setup to avoid this issue for my other extensions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Magento 2 Setup folder**

Step-1 for check with code extension

```
/dev/tests/static/testsuite/Magento/Test/Php/_files/phpcpd/blacklist
rename common.txt--
```

Step-2 run below command

```
php bin/magento dev:tests:run static
```

Step -3 see duplication code

```
dev/tests/static/report
phpcpd_report.xml
```

Now check `phpcpd_report.xml`

Comment: Hello nikhil, can you please explain in detail

Answer (score 6):

Here is some description for the Magento 2 command used to check code duplication.

The command to check code duplication/copy-paste is below.

```
php bin/magento dev:tests:run static
```

This command will first go to `dev/tests/static` folder. Here you can see declaration file **phpunit.xml.dist** for this test suite.

```
<testsuites>
    <testsuite name="Less Static Code Analysis">
        <file>testsuite/Magento/Test/Less/LiveCodeTest.php</file>
    </testsuite>
    <testsuite name="Javascript Static Code Analysis">
        <file>testsuite/Magento/Test/Js/LiveCodeTest.php</file>
    </testsuite>
    <testsuite name="PHP Coding Standard Verification">
        <file>testsuite/Magento/Test/Php/LiveCodeTest.php</file>
    </testsuite>
    <testsuite name="Code Integrity Tests">
        <directory>testsuite/Magento/Test/Integrity</directory>
    </testsuite>
    <testsuite name="Xss Unsafe Output Test">
        <file>testsuite/Magento/Test/Php/XssPhtmlTemplateTest.php</file>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

In this file, you will find above code which will define which file to execute for different code tests.

To narrow down you can see `PHP Coding Standard Verification` `testsuite` This will execute file **testsuite/Magento/Test/Php/LiveCodeTest.php**

When you open this file, you will find different functions to check for different types of code issues. The function which will be executed is `testCopyPaste`

```
public function testCopyPaste()
{
    $reportFile = self::$reportDir . '/phpcpd_report.xml';
    $copyPasteDetector = new CopyPasteDetector($reportFile);

    if (!$copyPasteDetector->canRun()) {
        $this->markTestSkipped('PHP Copy/Paste Detector is not available.');
    }

    $blackList = [];
    foreach (glob(__DIR__ . '/_files/phpcpd/blacklist/*.txt') as $list) {
        $blackList = array_merge($blackList, file($list, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES));
    }

    $copyPasteDetector->setBlackList($blackList);

    $result = $copyPasteDetector->run([BP]);

    $output = "";
    if (file_exists($reportFile)) {
        $output = file_get_contents($reportFile);
    }

    $this->assertTrue(
        $result,
        "PHP Copy/Paste Detector has found error(s):" . PHP_EOL . $output
    );
}
```

Here, you will find a code which will used to blacklist any file/folders from this code check.

```
foreach (glob(__DIR__ . '/_files/phpcpd/blacklist/*.txt') as $list) {
    $blackList = array_merge($blackList, file($list, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES));
}
```

This `foreach` function will check for any `.txt` file added in **dev/tests/static/testsuite/Magento/Test/Php/_files/phpcpd/blacklist** location. It will read the file and will ignore all the folders to exclude from copy paste code detection process.

After adding all blacklist files/folders to code, it will run below code.

```
$result = $copyPasteDetector->run([BP]);
```

This code will execute `run` function of **dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/CodingStandard/Tool/CopyPasteDetector.php** file.

```
public function run(array $whiteList)
{
    $blackListStr = ' ';
    foreach ($this->blacklist as $file) {
        $file = escapeshellarg(trim($file));
        if (!$file) {
            continue;
        }
        $blackListStr .= '--exclude ' . $file . ' ';
    }

    $vendorDir = require BP . '/app/etc/vendor_path.php';
    $command = 'php ' . BP . '/' . $vendorDir . '/bin/phpcpd' . ' --log-pmd ' . escapeshellarg(
            $this->reportFile
        ) . ' --names-exclude "*Test.php" --min-lines 13' . $blackListStr . ' ' . implode(' ', $whiteList);

    exec($command, $output, $exitCode);

    return !(bool)$exitCode;
}
```

Here, the code adds all the `blacklisted` folders/files in `--exclude` list.

After that it will run `vendor/bin/phpcpd` command.

Here in the command itself Magento has

excluded all 
`Test` files by code

```
--names-exclude "*Test.php"
```

It has also skipped all the code duplicates which are less than 13 lines by code

```
--min-lines 13
```

The output for this command execution will be added to the file defined in `testCopyPaste` function. The filename for copy-paste detection is **phpcpd_report.xml** located at **dev/tests/static/report** location.

After successful execution of the command, the output will be added to report files.

Comment: Can you suggest any solution to this question of code duplication -https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/191829/20064

Comment: Hello @nikhil 
can you please say me which line indicates the error like "This extension contains duplicated code." in phpcpd_report.xml