# Magento Marketplace submission Rejected - There are no commands defined in the "setup" namespace

Tags: magento-2.1, marketplace

I am trying to submit my extension to Magento Marketplace, I keep getting rejected.

Errors during installation

Installation issue:

```
setup-upgrade
```

The Error Message

[InvalidArgumentException]

```
There are no commands defined in the "setup" namespace.
```

This is what it says it failed on.
Operating System - Centos 7, PHP Version - 5.6.30, Magento Platform - 2.1.5 CE

When I test it. - Using Composer (or Manually adding file), (Dev and producution mode) everything seems to be working fine, no error messages anywhere.

Any ideas or things I can check?

Comment: It's looks like, They got error at the time of installation means at the time of run command: `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`. Install you module in new setup and run this command to check issue.

Comment: Also you can face this types of errors at the time of review refer this my answer: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/188489/35758

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this post where people is commenting all things an extension should needed in order to be successfully submitted to the marketplace:

[How to create a Marketplace ready Magento 2 extension](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/187509/how-to-create-a-marketplace-ready-magento-2-extension)