# Error while submitting Extension to Magento2

Tags: magento2, extensions

We have an extension released in Magento with version 1.3.1.

Now we are trying to upload the new extension with version 1.3.2.

This is our `composer.json`:

```
{

    "name": "celigo/magento2-netsuite-connector",
    "description": "A Magento 2 module for Celigo Magento2 NetSuite Connector",
    "type": "magento2-module",
    "version": "1.3.2",
    "license": [

    ],
    "require": {
        "php": "~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6",
        "magento/framework": "100.1.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "files": [ "registration.php" ],
        "psr-4": {
            "Celigo\Magento2NetSuiteConnector\": ""
        }
    }
}
```

On Technical Review i got this error:

```
Errors during installation

Please visit the Magento DevDocs guide in order to learn how to install extensions and use CLI.

Environment: Operating System - Centos 7, PHP Version - 7.0.23, Magento Platform - 2.1.9 CE

Command: composer require celigo/magento2-netsuite-connector:1.3.2'
Installation issue: Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1

The requested package celigo/magento2-netsuite-connector 1.3.2 exists as celigo/magento2-netsuite-connector[0.0.1, 1.1.0, 1.2.0, 1.3.0, 1.3.1] but these are rejected by your constraint.
Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] sh
[DockerOperationsPHP70Magento21CEVarnish] Running shell script

echo Failure
Failure
```

Why are they trying to install via composer if it does not exist in the composer via the command `composer require celigo/magento2-netsuite-connector:1.3.2`?

Can anyone please help me getting the extension submitted?

Comment: You should accept the answer to help other developers to find their solution.

Answer (score 1):

**As per Marketplace rule,**

> If you do not submit code within 1 month of the Approved from Business Review date we will assume the product has been abandoned and thus will reject it after 1 month.

See this answer for more details about failed in review: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/188489/35758

If you don't find any solution to your issue, then email to **`marketplace@magento.com`** for the issue.

## EDIT

I got mail from marketplace about this issue. This is marketplace core issue and they solved this issue at this morning.

**As per mail:**

> You are not doing anything wrong. we have identified a bug within our install automated testing and pushed a fix to production this morning. We are going to rerun the install tests today for affected extensions (I added your extension to this list).

Comment: The extension is already live with 1.3.1 version.
I am trying to upload a new version.

Already approved from Business Review

Comment: Then you can email to `marketplace@magento.com` about this issue.

Comment: @PrincePatel, But my business review approved few days ago. I am getting same error for this.

Comment: AnkurSachdeva and @Pushpendra Singh check my updated answer. This issue was from marketplace.