# Errors while submitting module in Magento Marketplace: Magento 2

Tags: magento2, module, marketplace, packaging

I created a custom module in Magento 2 and packaged it for submitting it to the Magento marketplace. The composer.json file is as below,

```
{
  "name": "vendor/module",
  "description": "text that describes the module",
  "type": "magento2-module",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": [
    "OSL-3.0",
    "AFL-3.0"
  ],
  "require": {
    "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|5.6.5|7.0.0|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6",
     "magento/framework": "~100.0.19"
     },
  "authors": [
    {
      "name": "Vendor",
      "email": "mail@domain.com",
      "homepage": "http://www.something.com/",
      "role": "Developer"
    }
  ],
  "autoload": {
    "files": [ "registration.php" ],
    "psr-4": {
      "Vendor\\Module\\": ""
    }
  }
}
```

After the packaging and submission of the module in Marketplace, the module was rejected from the technical review with Installation errors as below,

```
Command: setup:di:compile
Installation issue:
Proxies code generation... 1/7 [====>-----------------------] 14% 1 sec 44.0 MiB
Repositories code generation... 1/7 [====>-----------------------] 14% 1 sec 44.0 
MiB PHP Fatal error: Class 'Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Items\AbstractItems' not found in /var/www/html/vendor/vendor/module/Block/Adminhtml/Quote/View/Items/Renderer/DefaultRenderer.php on line 23
    [Pipeline] }
    [Pipeline] // stage
    [Pipeline] sh
    [DockerOperationsPHP70Magento20CEVarnish] Running shell script
    + echo Failure
    Failure
```

However, when I run the setup:di:compile in local I could not find any issue.
Also, the Class `Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Items\AbstractItems` does exist and working fine in local.

I have already gone through the relevant links as below but didn't find the solution.

- [Errors during installation- Submitting Package to Magento Marketplace](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/158910/errors-during-installation-submitting-package-to-magento-marketplace)
- [Installation issues on packaging a module: Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/207831/installation-issues-on-packaging-a-module-magento-2)
- [Error while submitting Extension to Magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/196571/error-while-submitting-extension-to-magento2)

I have no clue on what can be the issue out here. It has been a long time that I could not submit the module to marketplace since I am still stuck with the issues here.
Please, can anyone help?

Comment: Please check deploy mode in a local setup. It must be production mode. Becuase marketplace check module in production mode. You can check deploy mode by __php bin/magento deploy:mode:show__

Comment: @PrincePatel php bin/magento deploy:mode:show
Current application mode: production. (Note: Environment variables may override this value.).  The setup:di:compile still shows no errors for me.

Comment: In which place you used `Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Quote\AbstractQuote` ?

Comment: @KeyurShah In /var/www/html/vendor/vendorname/module/Block/Adminhtml/Quotes.php, my class Quotes extends \Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Quote\AbstractQuote

Comment: Any help will be highly appreciated.