# marketplace account creation

Tags: magento2, extensions, marketplace

I want to sell my extension on marketplace but when i tried to create the developer profile, there is a setting of vendorname which is recommended should be same like the VendorName of my module. My module vendor name is Nishu but marketplace profile is not accepting uppercase case letters.

any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is about selling the extension

Comment: @TejaBhagavanKollepara, Please check the question again. The user asking why his/her marketplace profile doe not accept the  `uppercase case letters`

Comment: @AmitBera, Yes Amit, I read the question already. That's why I chose this option because this will not do anythig with magento coding. Its about marketplace. If he/she still wants to ask question, it should be on magento meta

Answer (score 0):

> you can change it marketplace profile name capital to small

Vendor name must be same as vendor name in account information of Magento developer's account. You can find it from [developer.magento.com/account/profile](https://developer.magento.com/account/profile) `->Marketplace Profile->Vendor Name`.

also check this reference : https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/188489/68695

Comment: But i found somewhere that we cant change it once fixed and if there is any difference in name. Magento is not allowing us to upload a extension   https://marketplacesupport.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/360015771192-Vendor-name-change

Comment: yes but you can add vendor name "nishu" in `->Marketplace Profile->Vendor Name`

Comment: In that case, when i try to upload extension, magento is giving error that vendorname should match with the module VendorName..

Comment: @nishu Vendor name is same as vendor name in profile.

Comment: You mean to say if i use nishu in vendorname of magento profile and Nishu in my module... magento will count this as same... Right.. ?

Comment: yes same name @nishu