# How to avoid duplicate code error while upload extension on Magento marketplace

Tags: magento-2.1, overrides, marketplace, duplicate

I have developed a module which extends customer registration feature. In this module, I have overridden two controllers

**1. \Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\EditPost**

I have added custom method and call in `execute()` function

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Modulename\Controller\Account;

use Magento\Customer\Model\AuthenticationInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer\Mapper;
use Magento\Customer\Model\EmailNotificationInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey\Validator;
use Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerExtractor;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\InputException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\InvalidEmailOrPasswordException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\State\UserLockedException;

/**
 * Class EditPost
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 */
class EditPost extends \Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\EditPost
{
    /**
     * Form code for data extractor
     */
    const FORM_DATA_EXTRACTOR_CODE = 'customer_account_edit';

    /**
     * @var AccountManagementInterface
     */
    protected $customerAccountManagement;

    /**
     * @var CustomerRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $customerRepository;

    /**
     * @var Validator
     */
    protected $formKeyValidator;

    /**
     * @var CustomerExtractor
     */
    protected $customerExtractor;

    /**
     * @var Session
     */
    protected $session;

    /** @var EmailNotificationInterface */
    private $emailNotification;

    /**
     * @var ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    private $scopeConfig;

    /**
     * @var AuthenticationInterface
     */
    private $authentication;

    /**
     * @var Mapper
     */
    private $customerMapper;
    /**
     * Get authentication
     *
     * @return AuthenticationInterface
     */
    private function getAuthentication()
    {

        if (!($this->authentication instanceof AuthenticationInterfac•••••••••e)) {
            return ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(
                \Magento\Customer\Model\AuthenticationInterface::class
            );
        } else {
            return $this->authentication;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get email notification
     *
     * @return EmailNotificationInterface
     * @deprecated
     */
    private function getEmailNotification()
    {
        if (!($this->emailNotification instanceof EmailNotificationInterface)) {
            return ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(
                EmailNotificationInterface::class
            );
        } else {
            return $this->emailNotification;
        }
    }

    /**•••••••••
     * Change customer email or password action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        $validFormKey = $this->formKeyValidator->validate($this->getRequest());

        if ($validFormKey && $this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            $currentCustomerDataObject = $this->getCustomerDataObject($this->session->getCustomerId());
            $customerCandidateDataObject = $this->populateNewCustomerDataObject(
                $this->_request,
                $currentCustomerDataObject
            );
            try {
                // whether a customer enabled change email option
                $this->processChangeEmailRequest($currentCustomerDataObject);
                 // call my custom method
                $this->mycustommethod1($currentCustomerDataObject);
                // whether a customer enabled change password option
                $isPasswordChanged = $this->changeCustomerPassword($currentCustomerDataObject->getEmail());
                $this->customerRepository->save($customerCandidateDataObject);
                $this->getEmailNotification()->credentialsChanged(
                    $customerCandidateDataObject,
                    $currentCustomerDataObject->getEmail(),
                    $isPasswordChanged
                );
                $this->dispatchSuccessEvent($customerCandidateDataObject);
                $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('You saved the account information.'));
                return $resultRedirect->setPath('customer/account');
            } catch (InvalidEmailOrPasswordException $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
            } catch (UserLockedException $e) {
                $message = __(
                    'The account is locked. Please wait and try again or contact %1.',
                    $this->getScopeConfig()->getValue('contact/email/recipient_email')
                );
                $this->session->logout();
                $this->session->start();
                $this->messageManager->addError($message);
                return $resultRedirect->setPath('customer/account/login');
            } catch (InputException $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
                foreach ($e->getErrors() as $error) {
                    $this->messageManager->addError($error->getMessage());
                }
            } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addException($e, __('We can\'t save the customer.'));
            }

            $this->session->setCustomerFormData($this->getRequest()->getPostValue());
        }

        return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/edit');
    }

    /**
     * Get scope config
     *
     * @return ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    private function getScopeConfig()
    {
        if (!($this->scopeConfig instanceof \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface)) {
            return ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(
                \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface::class
            );
        } else {
            return $this->scopeConfig;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Account editing action completed successfully event
     *
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface $customerCandidateDataObject
     * @return void
     */
    private function dispatchSuccessEvent(\Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface $customerCandidateDataObject)
    {
        $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
            'customer_account_edited',
            ['email' => $customerCandidateDataObject->getEmail()]
        );
    }

    /**
     * Get customer data object
     *
     * @param int $customerId
     *
     * @return \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface
     */
    private function getCustomerDataObject($customerId)
    {
        return $this->customerRepository->getById($customerId);
    }

    /**
     * Create Data Transfer Object of customer candidate
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $inputData
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface $currentCustomerData
     * @return \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface
     */
    private function populateNewCustomerDataObject(
        \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $inputData,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface $currentCustomerData
    ) {
        $attributeValues = $this->getCustomerMapper()->toFlatArray($currentCustomerData);
        $customerDto = $this->customerExtractor->extract(
            self::FORM_DATA_EXTRACTOR_CODE,
            $inputData,
            $attributeValues
        );
        $customerDto->setId($currentCustomerData->getId());
        if (!$customerDto->getAddresses()) {
            $customerDto->setAddresses($currentCustomerData->getAddresses());
        }
        if (!$inputData->getParam('change_email')) {
            $customerDto->setEmail($currentCustomerData->getEmail());
        }
        //here start my custom code
        if (condition) {
            //my custom code
        }
        //here end my custom code
        return $customerDto;
    }
    /**
     * Change customer password
     *
     * @param string $email
     * @return boolean
     * @throws InvalidEmailOrPasswordException|InputException
     */
    protected function changeCustomerPassword($email)
    {
        $isPasswordChanged = false;
        if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('change_password')) {
            $currPass = $this->getRequest()->getPost('current_password');
            $newPass = $this->getRequest()->getPost('password');
            $confPass = $this->getRequest()->getPost('password_confirmation');
            if ($newPass != $confPass) {
                throw new InputException(__('Password confirmation doesn\'t match entered password.'));
            }

            $isPasswordChanged = $this->customerAccountManagement->changePassword($email, $currPass, $newPass);
        }

        return $isPasswordChanged;
    }
    /**
     * Process change email request
     *
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface $currentCustomerDataObject
     * @return void
     * @throws InvalidEmailOrPasswordException
     * @throws UserLockedException
     */
    private function processChangeEmailRequest(\Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface $currentCustomerDataObject)
    {
        if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('change_email')) {
            // authenticate user for changing email
            try {
                $this->getAuthentication()->authenticate(
                    $currentCustomerDataObject->getId(),
                    $this->getRequest()->getPost('current_password')
                );
            } catch (InvalidEmailOrPasswordException $e) {
                throw new InvalidEmailOrPasswordException(__('The password doesn\'t match this account.'));
            }
        }
    }
    //my custom method 
    private function mycustommethod1(\Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface $currentCustomerDataObject)
    {
       //my custom code
    }

    /**
     * Get Customer Mapper instance
     *
     * @return Mapper
     *
     * @deprecated
     */
    private function getCustomerMapper()
    {
        if ($this->customerMapper === null) {
            $this->customerMapper = ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Customer\Mapper');
        }
        return $this->customerMapper;
    }
}
```

**2.\Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\ForgotPasswordPost**

I have added if condition in `execute()` method.

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Modulename\Controller\Account;

use Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\SecurityViolationException;

class ForgotPasswordPost extends \Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\ForgotPasswordPost
{
    /**
     * Forgot customer password action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        $email = (string)$this->getRequest()->getPost('email');
        if ($email) {
            //here start my custom code
            if(condition)
            {
                //my custom code
            }
            //here end my custom code
            try {
                $this->customerAccountManagement->initiatePasswordReset(
                    $email,
                    AccountManagement::EMAIL_RESET
                );
            } catch (NoSuchEntityException $exception) {
                // Do nothing, we don't want anyone to use this action to determine which email accounts are registered.
            } catch (SecurityViolationException $exception) {
                $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($exception->getMessage());
                return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/forgotpassword');
            } catch (\Exception $exception) {
                $this->messageManager->addExceptionMessage(
                    $exception,
                    __('We\'re unable to send the password reset email.')
                );
                return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/forgotpassword');
            }
            $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage($this->getSuccessMessage($email));
            return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
        } else {
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('Please enter your email.'));
            return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/forgotpassword');
        }
    }
}
```

In overridden controllers, to access private methods I have to copy them in modules controller. When submitted my module to marketplace, I was given following error

> Code quality issues: CPD: This extension contains duplicated code.

With following details of files:-

```
   File: namespace/module-modulename/namespace-module-modulename-0.0.1.0/Controller/Account/EditPost.php
Line: 82
File: magento/module-customer/magento-module-customer-101.0.0.0-RC21/Controller/Account/EditPost.php
Line: 108
File: namespace/module-modulename/namespace-module-modulename-0.0.1.0/Controller/Account/EditPost.php
Line: 147
File: magento/module-customer/magento-module-customer-101.0.0.0-RC21/Controller/Account/EditPost.php
Line: 173
File: namespace/module-modulename/namespace-module-modulename-0.0.1.0/Controller/Account/EditPost.php
Line: 238
File: magento/module-customer/magento-module-customer-101.0.0.0-RC21/Controller/Account/EditPost.php
Line: 245
File: namespace/module-modulename/namespace-module-modulename-0.0.1.0/Controller/Account/ForgotPasswordPost.php
Line: 24
File: magento/module-customer/magento-module-customer-101.0.0.0-RC21/Controller/Account/ForgotPasswordPost.php
Line: 73 

this extension contains code that is directly copied from the Magento codebase. this is in direct violation of sections 3.1 and 9.1b of the Magento developer agreement.
```

All these errors were generated because of the private methods I copied from core controllers.
How can I solve this issue? as removing those private methods will break my module's functionality

Comment: Wait for some more time, someone will guide on this. Do not edit question just to bring it on top

Comment: this is really a problem. I think many functions in the core have just been declared private without further thinking because of the open closed principle. But many functions / attributes that are needed when extending the core are now private and leave no choice then copying / reimplementing them. Mostly those functions are legacy code that should not reside in the controller (in this example) and instead be in a separate reusable class

Comment: Can you add your code to the question so we can find a workaround?

Comment: I have updated my question with code.

Answer (score -1):

**Go to your Magento root**

**Step-1** Check code extension

```
/dev/tests/static/testsuite/Magento/Test/Php/_files/phpcpd/blacklist
```

rename **common.txt**--

**Step-2** run following command

```
php bin/magento dev:tests:run static
```

**Step - 3** Result -  see duplication code inside

```
dev/tests/static/report
```

**phpcpd_report.xml**

Now check **phpcpd_report.xml**